# How MySQL transaction isolation works?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

As I read from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2007/05/09/repeatable-read-isolation-level.aspx) if the transaction level is REPEATABLE-READ no other transaction can read data that being accessed by this transaction.But I found this when I testing.* (MySQL server version: 5.0.21-community-nt /innodb engine)*.

**Transaction A:**

```
mysql> SELECT @@tx_isolation;
+-----------------+
| @@tx_isolation  |
+-----------------+
| REPEATABLE-READ | 
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET autocommit = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE manufacturer
    -> SET lead_time = 22
    -> WHERE mcode = 'ACL';
Query OK, 1 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

**Transaction B**

```
mysql> set autocommit=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM Manufacturer ;
+-------+------------+-----------+
| mcode | mname      | lead_time |
+-------+------------+-----------+
| ACL   | ACL Cables |         2 | 
| HAY   | Haycarb    |         4 | 
| HYL   | Hayleys    |         5 | 
+-------+------------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The thing is I expected to transaction B to wait until the Transaction A to commit but it does not happen. How to apply this?

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: (MySQL server version: 5.0.21-community-nt /innodb engine) it is in the question.

Comment: Don't you need "start transaction" and "commit" statements?

Comment: Even used same result

Comment: Can you provide an example where the answer is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeatable Read applies within a single transaction. It says that you can read a value as often as you like within a transaction and you will get the same answer. Also there is no way to tell which transaction starts first, A or B. Furthermore, a transaction can be interrupted at any time, and another transaction run or continued. Your example does not reflect reality in that you run (on the command line) A first to completion then B to completion. This is serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Since transaction A shows:

```
... Changed: 0 ...
```

the record already had `lead_time` set to `2`, so the `UPDATE` didn't change anything, and transaction B simply sees the original value.